# Subcatecory listing how to center

Tags: magento-1.9, css, category-tree

We have add subcategory listing in home page, see picture:
[image: It is what we have now]

The all menu is centered to the complate page, it is possible to center the 3 subcateogry, see picture:
[image: This is what we need]

We can provide css and/or phtml.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to cenerized your menu or what

Comment: Yes same as the second picture, sorry if my explanation is bad. We already have center the complete menu, but now we want to center each link, so when have 3 link and not 4, the 3 link will be center to the complete menu

Comment: Can you please share your url

Comment: http://Pascolift.us/

Comment: Don't set Margin-left:6% set 1000px both menu & Main container

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I have change 6% to 1000px but now the complete menu is at right and main container we insert 1000px at margin-right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your LI element you've got a style:

```
.catblocks li {
   position: relative;
   float: left !important;
   list-style: none;
}
```

You have to remove the float: left !important, so change it to:

```
.catblocks li {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
}
```

Voila.

It still won't be exactly centered cause you have a 6% margin-left on `.cat-blocks`.

P.S. This is HTML/CSS related, not strictly Magento - shouldn't it be closed?

Comment: Just to let know other people, I have disable margin-left: 6% and disable margin-right: 2.66%.